# HTML email support for member registration

Tags: freemember, registration, register

Wondering how i can send a HTML email to a user upon registering, I am using Freemember which i believe uses the default EE Email Notification Templates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If an account is automatically activated then the activation email isn't sent. You could use [Registration Emails](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/registration-emails) or if you need more complex email functionality then use [Postmaster](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster).

Answer (score 2):

You need to first enable HTML emails in the [**Email Configuration**](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/cp/admin/email_configuration.html#default-mail-format) settings (Control Panel Location: Admin ‣ Email Configuration).

Then edit the [**Member Account Activation Instructions template**](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/cp/design/message_pages/index.html) and any other template you want served as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use MX Notify Control to fire an email using the Member Register trigger.